# ListView first item has wrong values

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, android-cursoradapter

I have a `ListView` which is filled by `CursorAdapter`. Each item of this `ListView` has 5 child `View`s. I set values of these child `View`s in my `CursorAdapter`'s `onBind()` (I'm using `ViewHolder` pattern). The values are these: phone number, call state, comments count, call duration, time when the call happened. If call was missed or dropped, I set the duration `View` to be `INVISIBLE`. Everything is fine while all the calls are "answered", but, if there appears a call that is missed or dropped then the first item in the `ListView`, I repeat ALWAYS AND ONLY THE FIRST ITEM, has the duration `View` set to be `INVISIBLE` and count `View` with wrong value. I don't get it. All the other first items `View`s are set correctly, but the duration is for some reason wrong. Please help me to figure this out.

This is my `CursorAdaper` code:

```
package com.example.nrsearch.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.nrsearch.R;
import com.example.nrsearch.Utils;

public class NumberListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
private static final String KEY_NUMBER = "number";
private static final String KEY_STATE = "state";
private static final String KEY_COUNT = "count";
private static final String KEY_TIME = "time";
private static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";

public NumberListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    private TextView numberView;
    private ImageView stateView;
    private TextView countView;
    private TextView timeView;
    private TextView durationView;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.i(Utils.TAG, "newView() is called");
    View view = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.numberlistitem, parent, false);

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.numberView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.number);
    holder.stateView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.state);
    holder.countView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
    holder.timeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
    holder.durationView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);

    view.setTag(holder);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
    Log.i(Utils.TAG, "bindView() is called");

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    holder.numberView.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_NUMBER)));
    int stateCode = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_STATE));
    if (stateCode == 0) holder.stateView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_arrow);
    else holder.stateView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_arrow);

    int count = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_COUNT));
    if (count == -2) holder.countView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.count_bubble_unknown);
    else if (count == -1) holder.countView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.count_bubble_blocked);
    else {
        holder.countView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.count_bubble);
        holder.countView.setText(""+count);
    }

    holder.timeView.setText(parseElapsedTime(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_TIME)),
            System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L));


    if (stateCode != 0) {
        long duration = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_DURATION));
        holder.durationView.setText(parseDuration(duration));
    } else holder.durationView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

private String parseElapsedTime(long pastTimeSecs, long presentTimeSecs) {
    long elapsedTimeSecs = presentTimeSecs - pastTimeSecs;
    if (elapsedTimeSecs >= 60L && elapsedTimeSecs < 3600L) {
        return "Pries " + Math.round(elapsedTimeSecs / 60L) + " min.";
    } else if (elapsedTimeSecs >= 3600L && elapsedTimeSecs < 86400L) {
        return "Pries " + Math.round(elapsedTimeSecs / 3600L) + " val.";
    } else if (elapsedTimeSecs >= 86400L && elapsedTimeSecs < 604800L) {
        return "Pries " + Math.round(elapsedTimeSecs / 86400L) + " d.";
    } else if (elapsedTimeSecs >= 604800L && elapsedTimeSecs < 2592000L) {
        return "Pries " + Math.round(elapsedTimeSecs / 604800L) + " sav.";
    } else if (elapsedTimeSecs >= 2592000L && elapsedTimeSecs < 31536000L) {
        return "Pries " + Math.round(elapsedTimeSecs / 2592000L) + " men.";
    } else if (elapsedTimeSecs >= 31536000L) {
        return "Pries " + Math.round(elapsedTimeSecs / 31536000L) + " m.";
    } else return "Pries " + Long.toString(elapsedTimeSecs) + " s.";
}

private String parseDuration(long timeSeconds) {
    int hours = Math.round(timeSeconds / 3600);
    int minutes = Math.round((timeSeconds - hours * 3600) / 60);
    long seconds = timeSeconds - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;

    String h, min, s;

    if (hours / 10 < 1)
        h = "0" + hours;
    else
        h = "" + hours;
    if (minutes / 10 < 1)
        min = "0" + minutes;
    else
        min = "" + minutes;
    if (seconds / 10 < 1)
        s = "0" + seconds;
    else
        s = "" + seconds;

    return h + ":" + min + ":" + s;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (stateCode != 0) {
       long duration = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_DURATION));
       holder.durationView.setText(parseDuration(duration));
       holder.durationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    } else{
       holder.durationView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Try setting the visibility to VISIBLE in the if clause. I had a problem with this recently.

Comment: Thank you. This was the right solution even though I found it myself before you answered.